# Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?

Tags: php, png, jpeg

I have a bunch of high quality PNG files.  I want to use PHP to convert them to JPG because of it's smaller file sizes while maintaining quality.  I want to display the JPG files on the web.

Does PHP have functions/libraries to do this?    Is the quality/compression any good?

Comment: Note that depending on what the images are, JPG won't always have a smaller file size than a PNG, so make sure you're using the right one for your situation.  http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Do this to convert safely a PNG to JPG with the transparency in white.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagedestroy($image);
$quality = 50; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
imagejpeg($bg, $filePath . ".jpg", $quality);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

Comment: This is much better, deals with transparency. Two top answers are now level pegging!

Comment: You just made my day a hell lot better mate! Thank you!

Comment: Does this code works for other type of source files, like bmp?

Comment: I know this is an old question but what makes this the most correct way to convert PNG to JPG? Wouldn't this simpler [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220228/4700944) suffice?

Answer (score 67):

Be careful of what you want to convert. JPG doesn't support alpha-transparency while PNG does. You will lose that information.

To convert, you may use the following function:

```
// Quality is a number between 0 (best compression) and 100 (best quality)
function png2jpg($originalFile, $outputFile, $quality) {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);
    imagejpeg($image, $outputFile, $quality);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

This function uses the [`imagecreatefrompng()`](http://docs.php.net/imagecreatefrompng) and the [`imagejpeg()`](http://docs.php.net/imagejpeg) functions from the GD library.

Comment: Please have a look at danLeon 's answer to convert PNG to JPG safely.

Answer (score 13):

This is a small example that will convert 'image.png' to 'image.jpg' at 70% image quality:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
imagejpeg($image, 'image.jpg', 70);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php
function createThumbnail($imageDirectory, $imageName, $thumbDirectory, $thumbWidth) {
    $explode = explode(".", $imageName);
    $filetype = $explode[1];

    if ($filetype == 'jpg') {
        $srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
    } else
    if ($filetype == 'jpeg') {
        $srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
    } else
    if ($filetype == 'png') {
        $srcImg = imagecreatefrompng("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
    } else
    if ($filetype == 'gif') {
        $srcImg = imagecreatefromgif("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
    }

    $origWidth = imagesx($srcImg);
    $origHeight = imagesy($srcImg);

    $ratio = $origWidth / $thumbWidth;
    $thumbHeight = $origHeight / $ratio;

    $thumbImg = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    imagecopyresized($thumbImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $origWidth, $origHeight);

    if ($filetype == 'jpg') {
        imagejpeg($thumbImg, "$thumbDirectory/$imageName");
    } else
    if ($filetype == 'jpeg') {
        imagejpeg($thumbImg, "$thumbDirectory/$imageName");
    } else
    if ($filetype == 'png') {
        imagepng($thumbImg, "$thumbDirectory/$imageName");
    } else
    if ($filetype == 'gif') {
        imagegif($thumbImg, "$thumbDirectory/$imageName");
    }
}
    ?>
```

This is a very good thumbnail script =)
Here's an example:

$path = The path to the folder where the original picture is.
$name = The filename of the file you want to make a thumbnail of.
$thumbpath = The path to the directory where you want the thumbnail to be saved into.
$maxwidth = the maximum width of the thumbnail in PX eg. 100 (wich will be 100px).

`createThumbnail($path, $name, $thumbpath, $maxwidth);`

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into [Image Magick](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), usually considered the de facto standard library for image processing. Does require an extra php module to be installed though, not sure if any/which are available in a default installation.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has some [image processing functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) along with the [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://docs.php.net/imagecreatefrompng) and [`imagejpeg` function](http://docs.php.net/imagejpeg). The first will create an internal representation of a PNG image file while the second is used to save that representation as JPEG image file.

Answer (score 2):

See [this list of php image libraries](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php). Basically it's GD or Imagemagick.

Answer (score 2):

*I know it's not an exact answer to the OP, but as answers have already be given...*

Do you really need to do this in PHP ?

What I mean is : if you need to convert a lot of images, doing it in PHP might not be the best way : you'll be confronted to `memory_limit`, `max_execution_time`, ...

*I would also say GD might not get you the best quality/size ratio ; but not sure about that (if you do a comparison between GD and other solutions, I am very interested by the results ;-) )*

Another approach, not using PHP, would be to use [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) via the command line *(and not as a PHP extension like other people suggested)*

You'd have to write a shell-script that goes through all `.png` files, and gives them to either

- [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to create a new `.jpg` file for each `.png` file
- or [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) to directly work on the original file and override it.

As a sidenote : if you are doing this directly on your production server, you could put some sleep time between bunches of conversions, to let it cool down a bit sometimes ^^

I've use the shell script + `convert`/`mogrify` a few times *(having them run for something like 10 hours one time)*, and they do the job really well :-)