# Converting PNG to JPEG file

Tags: php, gd

I have a script to convert PNG files to JPEG files. Except, I'm not exactly sure how it works. What do  use for $outputPngFile and $outputJpgFile? Can I do this with a tmp file, like when the user is uploading it? Then, how do I access the new file to move it to the proper image directory?

```
function pngTojpg($image, $outputPngFile, $outputJpgFile, $quality) {
$image = imagecreatefrompng($image);

//Save the png image
imagepng($image, $outputPngFile);         

//Save the jpeg image
imagejpeg($image, $outputJpgFile, $quality);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($image);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('yourlocation/image.png');
imagejpeg($image, 'yournewlocation/image.jpg', 70);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please break down what all the variables are?

Comment: Just save it to a new location instead of moving it?

Comment: This is more simple and 70 stands for compression so change that to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help you to know that you're using the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) that has been bundled with PHP.

What the function is doing is taking a path to a png image (`$image`), loading it into a GD resource that can be manipulated within PHP ([`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)), [saving the image as a png](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to the png output path (`$outputPngFile`), then [saving the image as a jpg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to the jpg output path (`$outputJpgFile`) with a particular compression factor (`$quality`), and finally [destroying the image resource object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php), since it isn't needed anymore.

Since it's saving the image as a png as well, the function was obviously intended to be used to save an image from either an external source (given by a URL) or temporary files from a user upload. You can do either, PHP doesn't care so long as the path you provide to the image file is valid.