# Transform .jpg, .jpeg or .gif to .png without saving them on machine

Tags: php, image, png, gd, transform

Is it possible to transform a .jpg, .jpeg or .gif image to .png in php without saving the image in your computer?
Something like:

```
function read_image($filename, $extension) {
    switch($extension) {
        case '.png':
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            break;
        case '.jpg': case '.jpeg':
            $unTransformed = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            $image = transform($unTransformed);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $unTransformed = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            $image = transform($unTransformed);
            break;
        return $image;
    }
}
function transform($unTransformed) {

    // Some magic here without actually saving the image to your machine when transforming

    return $transformed;
}
```

I honestly couldn't find an answer for this. Also note that GD is mandatory.

Comment: Have you seen this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431363/converting-during-upload-before-saving-on-server-png-gif-to-jpg

Comment: Just in case.. Dont store it and just return it as you are doing in your program..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using output buffering and capturing the output of imagepng should work, like this:

```
function transform($unTransformed) {
    ob_start();
    imagepng($unTransformed);
    $transformed = ob_get_clean();
    return $transformed;
}
```

Of course, this is assuming you actually want a variable containing a png bytestream of your image file.  If the only purpose is to output it anyways, don't bother and do as Marty McVry suggests.

Comment: This seems to bug :S Anyway, I need to do some colorizing on it.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the PHP manual: ([`imagepng()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)-function, which outputs a PNG image to either the browser or a file)

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$transformed = imagepng($untransformed);
```

You might encounter a problem sending the headers along, so it's possibly necessary to output the headers somewhere else or transform the stream created by `imagepng` to a base64-string and display the image like that, depending on the rest of  your code.