# How can I convert all images to jpg?

Tags: php, image-processing

I have script:

```
<?php

include('db.php');
session_start();
$session_id = '1'; // User session id
$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg");
if (isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
    if (strlen($name)) {
        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_formats)) {
            if ($size < (1024 * 1024)) { // Image size max 1 MB
                $actual_image_name = time() . $session_id . "." . $ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $actual_image_name)) {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
                    echo "<img src='uploads/" . $actual_image_name . "' class='preview'>";
                } else {
                    echo "failed";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid file format..";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please select image..!";
    }
    exit;
}

?>
```

Is possible convert all images (png, gif etc) to jpg with 100% quality? If yes, how? I would like allow to upload png and gif, but this script should convert this files to jpg. Is possible this with PHP?

Comment: Look at this discussion, it was already answered

[Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression

Comment: its about converting png to jqg @DavideBerra

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this code: `originalImage` is the path of... the original image... `outputImage` is self explaining enough. `Quality` is a number from 0 to 100 setting the output jpg quality (0 - worst, 100 - best)

```
function convertImage($originalImage, $outputImage, $quality)
{
    // jpg, png, gif or bmp?
    $exploded = explode('.',$originalImage);
    $ext = $exploded[count($exploded) - 1]; 

    if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage);
    else if (preg_match('/png/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
    else if (preg_match('/gif/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefromgif($originalImage);
    else if (preg_match('/bmp/i',$ext))
        $imageTmp=imagecreatefrombmp($originalImage);
    else
        return 0;

    // quality is a value from 0 (worst) to 100 (best)
    imagejpeg($imageTmp, $outputImage, $quality);
    imagedestroy($imageTmp);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: call this function instead of move_uploaded_file

Comment: Use $ext == 'png' and like instead of preg_match - it works too and is slightly faster. Also, I use strtolower on $ext before the check, to handle extensions like .JPG correctly. Otherwise, excelent function, helped me a lot. +1

Comment: the /i in preg_match makes the check case insensitive

Comment: One may assume that passing $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'] as the $originalImage would work, but it happens to save the file as XXXXX.tmp, so the extension didn't worked. Passing $_FILES['photoimg']['name'] instead will give the correct extension, but fail to create the image (it's getting a string instead of an object. So to solve that, you may pass both info, $originalImage and $originalName and edit the function accordingly, other than that, thanks a lot Davide for a great function i've been using for years now

Comment: i would add $ sign at the end of every reg. pattern. Why? what about uploaded file named: **iAmjpegWithGifAndPngTypedInName.bmp** . Dollar sign will ensure that there is nothing after the extension matched in pattern

Comment: what about convert to HEIC?

Answer (score 11):

Try using `Imagick` `setImageFormat`, for me it provides the best image quality 
http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageformat.php

```
$im = new imagick($image);

// convert to png
$im->setImageFormat('png');

//write image on server
$im->writeImage($image .".png");
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Answer (score 8):

Davide Berra's answer is great, so I improved the file type detection a little, using **exif_imagetype()** instead of relying on the file extension:

```
/**
*   Auxiliar function to convert images to JPG
*/
function convertImage($originalImage, $outputImage, $quality) {

    switch (exif_imagetype($originalImage)) {
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $imageTmp=imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $imageTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $imageTmp=imagecreatefromgif($originalImage);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_BMP:
            $imageTmp=imagecreatefrombmp($originalImage);
            break;
        // Defaults to JPG
        default:
            $imageTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage);
            break;
    }

    // quality is a value from 0 (worst) to 100 (best)
    imagejpeg($imageTmp, $outputImage, $quality);
    imagedestroy($imageTmp);

    return 1;
}
```

You must have **php_exif** extension enabled to use this.

Comment: With exit_imagetype you can also convert broken images or images that have been converted. Works much better than the answer from Davide. Strage that that got the tick, and not this.

Answer (score 3):

A small code to convert `image.png` to `image.jpg` at desired image quality:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
imagejpeg($image, 'image.jpg', 70); // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

a small fix to davide's answer, the correct function for converting from BMP is "imagecreatefrom**w**bmp" instead of imagecreatefrombmp (missing "w")
also you should consider that png may be transparent, [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105802/convert-image-format-png-to-jpeg-without-saving-to-disk-php) a way to fill it with white BG (jpeg can't apply alpha data).

```
function convertImage($originalImage, $outputImage, $quality){
// jpg, png, gif or bmp?
$exploded = explode('.',$originalImage);
$ext = $exploded[count($exploded) - 1]; 
if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i',$ext)){$imageTmp=imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImage);}
else if (preg_match('/png/i',$ext)){$imageTmp=imagecreatefrompng($originalImage);}
else if (preg_match('/gif/i',$ext)){$imageTmp=imagecreatefromgif($originalImage);}
else if (preg_match('/bmp/i',$ext)){$imageTmp=imagecreatefromwbmp($originalImage);}
else    {    return false;}
// quality is a value from 0 (worst) to 100 (best)
imagejpeg($imageTmp, $outputImage, $quality);
imagedestroy($imageTmp);
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From PhpTools:

```
/**
 * @param string $source (accepted jpg, gif & png filenames)
 * @param string $destination
 * @param int $quality [0-100]
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function convertToJpeg($source, $destination, $quality = 100) {

    if ($quality < 0 || $quality > 100) {
        throw new \Exception("Param 'quality' out of range.");
    }

    if (!file_exists($source)) {
        throw new \Exception("Image file not found.");
    }

    $ext = pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext)) {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } else if (preg_match('/png/i', $ext)) {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    } else if (preg_match('/gif/i', $ext)) {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Image isn't recognized.");
    }

    $result = imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Exception("Saving to file exception.");
    }

    imagedestroy($image);
}
```