# How to write a PHP file converter?

Tags: php, image, file, png, converters

I would like to create a file converter. I mean `png` to `jpg` or something. I tried so much things like this :

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(input)), 'out.png');
```

Do you have an example?

Comment: Well your solution is the best for jpg to png. The converter depends on the specific file extension, there is not a 'general' way to do it

Comment: There seems to be plenty of examples online. Did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549446/how-can-i-convert-all-images-to-jpg#answer-14549647  ?

Comment: This seems to be an attempt at starting a discussion rather than a question. Consider asking “how do I convert from PNG to JPEG in PHP?” instead, though there’s probably already a question for that for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from a file, in this case an image by using file_get_contents:

```
$data = file_get_contents("img.png");
```

Once you have the data to form the new file, you can then use the function file_put_contents to write your new file:

```
if (file_put_contents("img.jpg", $data)) {
    echo("success");
} else {
    echo("failure");
}
```

file_put_contents returns an int of 0 or 1 so you can determine if it was successful in creating the file.

You could then create the following function:

```
function imagepng($input, $output) {
    return file_put_contents($output, $input);
}
```

Hope this is helpful.