# PHP renaming of input file issues

Tags: php

I'm trying to rename the input file to be a .jpg after conversion, but for some reason I'm getting a file.png.jpg when I'm really looking for file.jpg

Here is my code:

```
$source = $path . $_POST['username']. "-" . $_FILES['t1']['name'];
$destination = $path . $_POST['username']. "-" . basename($_FILES['t1']['name']) . ".jpg";
```

Comment: and the $_FILES['t1']['name'] = file.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)**:

```
$source = $path . $_POST['username']. "-" . $_FILES['t1']['name'];
$path_parts = pathinfo( $_FILES['t1']['name'] );
$destination = $path . $_POST['username']. "-" . $path_parts['filename'] . ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the variable `$filename` contains your image name with the png extension.

In order to change the extension to jpg , simply run it through this function :

```
function replace_extension($filename) {
    return preg_replace('/\..+$/', '.' . '.jpg', $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `basename()` function includes the original files extension

Use the [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function to return an array of informatino about the file and use the filename with out the extension

Replace

```
$destination = $path . $_POST['username']. "-" . basename($_FILES['t1']['name']) . ".jpg";
```

with

```
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['t1']['name']);
$destination = $path . $_POST['username']. "-" . $info['filename'] . ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the second parameter to basename to kill the suffix

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['t1']['name'], ".png");
```

or you could do some string manipulation

```
$filename = substr($_FILES['t1']['name],0, strrpos($_FILES['t1']['name'], ".") -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`basename` returns you the whole filename, including the file type suffix (i.e. ".jpg"). If you want to strip the suffix, you can call the function with a second parameter: `basename($_FILES['t1']['name'], 'png')`.

But if you want to convert a png to a jpg, you can't just change the filename, you have to convert the file using special functions, see "[Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression)".