# Use PHP to convert PNG data into JPG data

Tags: php, gd

I'm currently using the following code to call a dynamic URL and get the image data I need for a thumbnail:

```
$thumb_url = $thumbUrl."?key=".$key."&document=".$document."&width=148&height=148";
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 120;
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $thumb_url);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$thumb_content = curl_exec($crl);
@curl_close($crl);
```

Once I have the data inside thumb_content, I can write it as a PNG to the file system.  This works great as-is, however, I need a way to convert this and save it as a JPG instead.

I was reviewing this question, but it seems to read and write from the file system while doing the conversion:  [Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression/1201822#1201822)

Unless absolutely necessary, I don't want to write anything to the file system until I'm ready to write the final JPG.  I'd like to just work with the stream data.

Comment: `imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring($thumb_content), 'foo.jpg');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents`:

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($thumb_url));
if ($img !== false)
    imagejpeg($img, "/path/to/save/file.jpg");
```

Comment: Is it possible to set $thumb_img = imagejpeg($img) and write the physical file a little differently?

Comment: You can store it in a var with something like:
ob_start();
imagejpeg($img); 
$img2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();