# Save all uploaded images (png, gif ) as jpg using php

Tags: php, image, upload

How i can save all uploaded images as jpg using php. 
i have code php to upload images like this

```
 $upload_dir="../uploads/";
 $filename = $_FILES['pic1']['name'];    
 $tmp_name=$_FILES['pic1']['tmp_name'];
 $path=$upload_dir.$filename;
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);
```

i am using

```
     $image_path=imagecreatefromjpeg($path); 
     `imagejpeg($image_path);`
```

but not work!.

Comment: add imagedestroy($image_path);

Comment: Take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because you tell PHP to create image from jpeg format and your uploaded file is gif or png. You could use [imagecreatefromstring()](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromstring) function:

```
$image_path = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path));
imagejpeg($image_path);
```