# How could I compress $_FILES image with php?

Tags: php, file, post, compression

I would like to compress image from user. I thought I could use GD, so  I wrote code like this.

```
   imagepng($_FILES['upload_file'], NULL, 6)
```

But this was wrong. Can I compress image from user with imagepng? 
(I dont have to save this file from user because I write the code in other place.)
Please tell me.

Comment: You had better tell us exactly what you mean by compress. Do you mean something like zippping the image, or do you mean making the image into a thumbnail for example

Comment: I know jpg has compression levels, but I was unaware of png having them... unless you mean reducing the image size, or color bit table, or stripping previews/xinfos/etc...

Comment: I would like to reduce the volume of data. For example, if user upload 3mb image, I would like to reduce the volume and save the file with like 1mb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression)