# Automatically add dark background to white-on-transparent PNGs

Tags: javascript, php

We have a script that displays PNGs uploaded to out DB on a page with a white background.

This works perfectly fine for 99% of the images.

Where it does not work is when the uploaded PNG is white-on-transparent, in which case we just see nothing but white space.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically detect such images and add a dark background for the div where the PNG is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert png to jpg using php:
 [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951540/11255460) 
(Instead of saving the white backround you can set your RGB to black (0,0,0) )

Or use
powerful php library where you can edit images its called [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine)  
 
and there you can change alpha to black color
For useful examples you can visit 
 [Docs](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/introduction.html#basic-usage)

To get file extension you can use
`pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Adding the background is not the issue. The issue is figuring out whether the background should be white or black based on the content of the PNG.