# Add watermark in image in using PHP

Tags: php, watermark

I'm trying to add a watermark in a image using the PHP code found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php), but the output of this code is this:

[image]

The code i did is this:

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('http://localhost:8080/sisop/storage/app/public/files/16522147787.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost:8080/sisop/storage/app/public/files/16527077747.jpg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - 
$marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

I don't know if i did something wrong, or if the code doesn't work anymore, but any help here would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: The code seems to work I guess. Can you try downloading instead of seeing it inline? Your header is wrong: Change `header('Content-type: image/png');` to `header('Content-type: image/png'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Image.png"');`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: with this header you've sended, i automatically download the file, but when opened, it shows an error and i can't see the image.. but i don't want to download the image, but i want to just display the image with the watermark

Comment: Ah, so there's indeed some error in the PNG. Are the original PNGs workable? Try opening those PNG files? In my local example, I had two PNG files and not one PNG and one JPG.

Comment: The PNG files open fine! also the JPEG one!

Comment: Can you try to convert both the files into PNG? I mean the JPG into PNG as well and try? PHP might be finicky sometimes with ImageMagick, which I suppose you're using to do stuff?

Comment: Oh, I just saw [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php) actually works too. Maybe either of image is not recognised by PHP?

Comment: Also check this one too: [Use PHP to convert PNG to JPG with compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951540)

Comment: I actually don't even know what ImageMagick is.. lol.. I just tried to do this with both PNGs, but i'm still getting an image with error

Comment: I believe `imagecreatefrompng()` needs ImageMagick runtime in the background. I maybe wrong. :)

Comment: Do you think your programme has a space or some UTF-8 BOMs? Do you suspect the file has issues? `:(` Can you post the complete file for me please?

Comment: well.. i thought the code would work by itself, since it has no mention of any dependency needed

Comment: ImageMagick most of the time comes with PHP and Unix based machines. Oh wait a minute. What OS are you working with? 

Comment: I'm working in Windows 10.. The complete file you mean is my blade file ? I added  this php inside my home.blade.php file just so i can test it

Comment: Woah. That's getting way too complex now. **1.** I am not sure if this works reliably in Windows. **2.** Blade file? That's taking into a different league of a problem! 

Comment: Why is that ? ahhaah sorry for my ignorance... But do you know a way to do this reliably in a windows enviroment ?

Comment: I'm doing this project locally, and soon it will be deployed in a Linux enviroment

Comment: Have you tried using Vagrant + ScotchBox - I was using that on Windows for long.

Comment: Here you go: [GitHub - scotch-io/scotch-box-pro: Scotch Box Pro is a preconfigured Vagrant Box with a full array of LAMP Stack features to get you up and running with Vagrant in no time.](https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box-pro)